# Visual studio 2015 does not run tests

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I am struggling with an issue on Vs 2015 and Resharper ultimate. It seems that every now and then the test runner gets blocked and I get the following behaviour:

[image]

debug/ run selected tests button is disabled.

If i run the tests with resharper I get a green progress bar that goes indefinetly from left to right:

[image]

It seems that the test runner is blocked but I have no idea where it gets blocked.

Comment: same happend to me.